# Illegal modifier for parameter closeApplication; only final is permitted

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I created a class called BaseClass that will be extended in the InvalidLogin class. In the BaseClass class there is a method that is displaying the following error messages:

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
    - Syntax error, insert "[ ]" to complete Dimension
    - Syntax error on token "closeApplication", AnnotationName expected after 
     this token
    - void[] is an invalid type
    **- Illegal modifier for parameter closeApplication; only final is permitted**

Below are both classes cited above and the error images presented by Eclipse.

```
    public class BaseClass {

    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeClass
    public void setupApplication() {
        Reporter.log("Instanciando o navegador", true);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://enterprise.demo.orangehrmlive.com/symfony/web/index.php/auth/login");
        Reporter.log("Aplicação inicializada", true);

        @AfterClass
        public  void closeApplication() {
            driver.quit();
            Reporter.log("Sessão do navegador finalizada");
        }       
    }
}


    public class InvalidLogin extends BaseClass {

    @Test(description = "This Test Case will perform valid login")
    public void loginApplicationValid() {
        try {
            driver.findElement(By.name("txtUsername")).sendKeys("Admin1");
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("admin1");
            driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
            driver.navigate().back();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Test(description = "This Test Case will perform invalid login")
    public void loginApplicationInvalid() {
        driver.findElement(By.name("txtUsername")).sendKeys("admin1");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")).sendKeys("admin2");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
    }
}
```

[Print Erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBhuV.jpg)

[Print Erro 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etdb6.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not closing the method setupApplication properly. Just add closing bracket before the method closeApplication  as given below.

```
public class BaseClass {

WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public void setupApplication() {
    Reporter.log("Instanciando o navegador", true);
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://enterprise.demo.orangehrmlive.com/symfony/web/index.php/auth/login");
    Reporter.log("Aplicação inicializada", true);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public  void closeApplication() {
        driver.quit();
        Reporter.log("Sessão do navegador finalizada");
    }
```

}